# Does using AWS Cloud9 costs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud9, aws-cloud9

I am starting to use AWS Cloud9, I created an environment and played a little bit with the editor but I haven't seen any notice that says if it costs. Is this service free?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/cloud9/pricing/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service itself is free, but in can be installed on an underlying ec2 instance, and you have to pay for that if you do.